# MySQL SELECT * fails upon Unicode

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Background Information: I have a table of country_types. The charset is set to utf8mb4 and the colation is set to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci.

When I run `SELECT * FROM DB.country_types;` I get the following:

[image: Result of: SELECT * FROM DB.country_types in MySQL Workbench]

However, as you can see entry number 29 is missing. When I filter to entry 29, it shows me entry 29, eventhough the SELECT * statement doesn't select entry 29.

[image: Result of: Filter for entry 29]

Entry 29 uses a special unicode character unlike the other rows. I was wondering how I could fix this problem in order to return entry 29 in the SELECT statement.

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM DB.country_types ORDER BY country_id` returns?

Comment: @GMB It returns Entry 29 properly. My question is why wouldn't the normal SELECT * return that entry? Given the encoding and collation of the table.

Comment: It is probably at the end of the list. Without an order by clause, a select statement returns an unordered list.

Comment: You probaly have an index on `(name)` and the engine decided to read the records from the index ordered my `name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run `SELECT * FROM DB.country_types` [...], as you can see entry number 29 is missing.

It is not missing, it is just not showing at the place where you expect it to be. It is not a matter of encoding.  You have to keep in mind that, in any SQL database, records are *unordered*, unless an `ORDER BY` clause is specified. When no such clause is specified, the order of the records returned by the query is unpredictable.

If you want to consistently see entry 29 between 28 and 30, you need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query, like:

```
SELECT * FROM DB.country_types ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I restarted my computer and my MySQL Workbench and it showed up. It was not ordered despite all other entries being ordered. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Welcome @WarrenNiles! Bottom line, do not assume anything about some inherent ordering of the records... Unless an `ORDER BY` clause is present.